# expo-constants in react native how and where should i add it

Tags: react-native, expo

Your project is accessing the following APIs from a deprecated global rather than a module import: Constants (expo-constants).

The global "__expo" and "Expo" objects will be removed in SDK 41. Learn more about how to fix this warning: https://expo.fyi/deprecated-globals

I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I don't understand where should I add expo constants

Comment: if possible show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1**

`expo install expo-constants`

**Step 2**

Search your project for `Constants` string (exact match) and then import it with `import Constants from 'expo-constants';`. Also, remove any other `Constants` import that you might already have in that file.

If the problem still persist take a deeper look on [Deprecated globals](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/deprecated-globals.md), maybe some of the packages you're using are not compatible version with your project's Expo SDK version.